# How can maven reporting plugin add a menu with programmatically created items?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I would like to develop a plugin that automatically generates menu items in a site submenu, each referencing a file on local directory.

It should be similar to how `modules` or `reports` are added to the `site.xml` descriptor:

```
<menu ref="reports" name="Reports"/>
```

except that I want to have my own ID and a chance to populate that menu:

```
<menu ref="my-subtree" name="My Menu Tree"/>
```

I have explored a lot of code in `maven-site-plugin` and `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` but could not find the trick to add the menu items.

I will appreciate any hints or ideally pointers to code samples.

Comment: Only the reports parts can be enhanced by report plugins to create entries in the navigation. Have you inherited from `AbstractMavenReport`?

Comment: yes I do - it generates a page - but I want it to generate also some menu items under an existing menus